# Amadeus get Token Failed with status Code 400

Tags: javascript, amadeus

i'm trying to get access token for test some APIs like Hotels Search but Token Api Failed With Status Code: 400

```
    code: 38187
    error: "invalid_request"
    error_description: "Mandatory grant_type form parameter missing"
    title: "Invalid parameters"
```

the Payload Which i sent with the request

```
client_id: "y028t70JGLM431t0X..."
client_secret : "XO4Hk8X1bK..."
grant_type: "client_credentials"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the cURL with the headers and payload according to the [authorization](https://amadeus4dev.github.io/developer-guides/API-Keys/authorization/) guide.

```
curl "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
     -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}"
```